# OneDrive folder nested in another OneDrive folder

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I want to set my OneDrive folder to be on a different disk device (D:).  Ideally, it should  appear as D:/OneDrive, with everything inside this folder.  But, after moving it, I now get this ugly situation:

[image]

Why am I getting a second OneDrive folder within the first, and Personal Vault (which I never use) is in the top level folder?  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you synchronizing your Desktop to OneDrive? Please [edit] to include this vital information.  Is there anything contained in this inner OneDrive directory?

Comment: @Ramhound do you mean the back up of Desktop, Documents, etc that it asks when you set up OneDrive?  If so, no I don't.  All of my files are contained in the inner directory.  I want to have everything in D:/OneDrive, not D:/OneDrive/OneDrive.  This was how it was when it resided in my user folder.

Comment: When selecting which folder to use for onedrive, select the root (D:\) instead of D:\Onedrive

Comment: @Gantendo I have already tried this, it gives the same result.  I even tried just letting it go to it's default location in my user folder.  It still does this two level nonsense even there, where it didn't before.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, because for the life of me I still don't know how it happened, but all of my files were also under a second-level OneDrive folder in the cloud as well.  Moving the files up one level and deleting the rogue OneDrive folder from onedrive.com fixed it.